# How to decode internal errors and probable causes?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors

I've been typing for a long time to get compilable code.
Because I'm implementing an interface with quite a lot of members.

Halfway though the process I have something that compiles, but now XE2 strikes me with an internal error:

> [DCC Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: L2095

Problem is that it's hard to rewind, because the last time I had compilable code was when I had 2000 fewer lines.

Is there a way to decode the internal error so that I have an inkling of that's causing the compiler to break down?

*Note that I did not tag this question XE2, because the issue of internal errors is not limited to this version*

Comment: Does this happen consistently? I've noticed that often such errors arise when I've made numerous changes to a complex group of interfaces and/or classes, but if I save everything, shut down Delphi (XE) and restart, the problem disappears. And yes, the issue is not limited to XE2 - I've been seeing it on occasion since at least Delphi 5  and now in XE - but saving and restarting Delphi always seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Restart the IDE. It usually self-corrects.

Comment: @Vector, David No restarting never helps.

Answer (score 3):

Internal errors are errors in the *compiler* or *linker*. The codes you get, like `L2095`, have no meaning for us users. They only have meaning for those who actually write the compiler and linker, i.e. for the developers at Embarcadero.

FWIW, I've been told the number is a hint where exactly the error occurs (line number?), and the letter in which part of the compiler/linker combo. Not useful for us mere mortals, though, sorry.

And before you ask: I don't know of a comprehensive list of internal errors and how to avoid or work around them. You could google them, or look in [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/) if yours is mentioned and if there is a workaround.

### Update

See Andrei Galatyn's comment and [the link in there](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Resolving_Internal_Errors_%28Delphi%29) for some help on resolving internal errors.

Comment: You posted it few minutes earlier than me, so i delete my answer :) But i think this link can be useful: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Resolving_Internal_Errors_%28Delphi%29

Comment: @andrei It's fine for there to be multiple answers. If you feel yours adds something not send by the other answers, leave it.